# How to signin/login to a website programmatically?

Tags: android, authentication

I am new to android. I am creating an application in which user authentication is needed, but to authorize application user needs to login first. After that the data can be received. I just wanna know is there any procedure to login to a remote website if there is no login api available for that.
i am waiting for the reply.
Thanks,
Arun

Comment: @user441432: That is a question you need to ask of whoever wrote the "remote website".

Answer (score 0):

May be you can talk to your website with a REST interface ? I dont know. but may be you can try to use kind of HttpClient objects to dialog with the website. You can use HttpGet to make a request via the GET_METHOD. There are other method to use. Well, if you seach a bit on the web about these objects/method you should see some examples. Hope its help you.

Comment: More likely to be POST than GET

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPClient to do this, it gives you access to cookies and caching mechanisms, so it's all you need to implement this.